# Regarding getting Date - n days Date

Tags: shell, date

Suppose I have a particular date stored in a variable `date_m`. I want `((date_m)-25)` date.

For example: I have `15/09/2014` stored in my variable , then I want `21/08/2014` returned if I subtract 25 from the date stored in variable.

Answer (score 13):

With the GNU implementation of `date`, to display yesterday's date, enter:

```
$ date --date="1 days ago"
```

OR

```
$ date --date="-1 day"
```

For your question:

```
$ date --date="25 days ago"
```

OR

```
$ date --date="-25 day"
```

For using it with variables, you can use `$()`:

```
pastDate=$(date --date="-25 day")
echo "$pastDate"
```

For general case `n` days and for a specific date:

```
#!/bin/bash
date1="Tue Sep 2 07:53:47 EEST 2014"
echo "Before? "
read n
date --date="$date1 -$n day"
```

[Source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-get-yesterdays-tomorrows-date.html)

Comment: GNU `date` does not parse `15/09/2014` as a valid date though.

Answer (score 1):

In the following the date and number of days are declared.

The script turns the dates in seconds and computes what timepoint 1 (`Tp1`) is if the number of days (in seconds) is subtracted from the given timepoint 2 (`Tp2`). In the end seconds is converted back in date.

```
Date_m=2014/09/15
Days=25
Seconds=$(echo "$Days"*60*60*24| bc -l)
Tp2date=$(date -d "$Date_m" +%Y/%m/%d)
Tp2sec=$(date -d "$TD" +%s)
Tp1sec=$(echo "$TDsec"-"$Seconds"| bc -l)
Tp1date=$(date -d @$Tp1sec)
echo "$Tp1date"
```

Comment: The format of the date is `15/09/2014`, not with the year first.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat belatedly, here is one way to handle non-US dd/mm/yyyy format dates with the 25 day relative adjustment:

```
date_m='15/09/2014'
date --date "$(IFS=/ read d m y <<<"$date_m"; echo "$m/$d/$y - 25 days")" +%d/%m/%Y

21/08/2014
```

It does assume a shell such as `bash` that's capable of handling a string redirection `<<<`, and GNU `date`.